# Excel VBA SQL returning different results vs Access DB SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a query that works something like this:

```
Select sales from salesTable where product like "abc*"
```

I put the same query in my Excel VBA script and at first it returns empty.
So I changed the query to use `%` instead of `*`, which you apparently have to do.

```
Select sales from salesTable where product like "abc%"
```

Now it returns a result but the result is different from what's pulled in MS Access.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the connection and query strings?

Comment: Is this question resolved? Other than the wildcards, how are the results different? Please illustrate with data.

Comment: resolved by using ALIKE

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a difference between ADO and DAO. Try using `ALIKE` instead of `LIKE`.

eg:

```
where product ALIKE "abc*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "%" wildcard in Access. Try using "%" in both queries.